# Need help setting up CLANG on windows Properly

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, window, clang

I need some help to set up clang on windows properly.

I have visual studios 2015 installed. And the Windows SDK.
I recently installed Clang, and ran a very basic hello world through it to make sure it's working correctly. And it gave me an error I can't make any sense out of.

Visual Studios will handle this just fine.

Here is the error output I've received from clang:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]

C:\Users\Leo>cd C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Sandbox

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Sandbox>clang++ hello.cpp
In file include d from hello.cpp:1:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\iostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\istream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ostream:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\ios:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xlocnum:6:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\climits:5:
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\yvals.h:8:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h:10:10: fatal error:
  'corecrt.h' file not found
#include <corecrt.h>
         ^
1 error generated.

C:\Users\Leo\Desktop\Sandbox>
```

Line 1 in hello.cpp is just:

```
#include <iostream>
```

So this error isn't making sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Type `echo %INCLUDE%` at the command prompt.   To see your INCLUDE path.

Check to make sure your `INCLUDE` environment variable isn't set to a path that contains a Visual Studio path.  Probably will need to do the same for the `LIB`environment variable as well.

Comment: echo %INCLUDE% only returns %INCLUDE%. So I typed "set INCLUDE" and learned that the paths were not defined. What do I need to define them to? Also, I thought CLANG requires either Windows SDK or Visual Studios for its includes.

Comment: `<corecrt.h>` is in the Windows SDK path.  On my install, there are two copies, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10150.0\ucrt\corecrt.h` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\corecrt.h`

Comment: Thank you. I took a look at my visual studio's dev environment and used those paths. Everything's working well now.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got it to work correctly, and compile windows applications. Including Directx11 and Directx12.

Turns out you would need to build Clang under Visual Studios after generating a Cmake project. If you wish to default to 64bit, you need to specify the 64bit version of Visual Studios.

Once it's compiled, you need to run clang-cl under the VSbuild tools.